# Vue method being called twice when referencing the $children

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm building a tab widget, and I'm having an issue where the `testFn()` is called twice when I assign the `$children` components to the `tabs` data property. Not sure what is causing it.

I have a parent component that looks like this:

```
mounted() {
    this.tabs = this.$children;
  },
 methods: {
    testFn(i) {
      console.log("fn called" + i);
    },
}
```

The Template of the parent component:

```
<ul>
   <li v-for="(tab, index) in tabs")>..test..</li>
</ul>

<AppUiButton @click="testFn(selectedTab + 1)"> Test </AppUiButton>
```

`testFn()` is called twice for some reason.

This, however, works as expected:

```
mounted() {
    // this.tabs = this.$children;
  },
```

Why does the fact that I'm assigning `this.tabs` to the $children change the behavior of the `@click`?

Comment: Can you add a fiddle/snippet to test the code ?

Comment: Is that object that you show the definition for `AppUiButton`?

Comment: @zero298 no, that is the definition or a parent component. `AppUiButton` is rendered in this parent.
@Zysce I'll try to setup a fiddle in the meantime

Comment: Added clarification. Also, the issue seems to happen only when I use the `tabs` inside of the `<li>`